# Is there any phrase for journalists lies?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I need a word or a phrase or expression for journalists lies.. There must be something...

Comment: Welcome Amina Sa, can you add some context to your question and also include any research you've done to find such a word or phrase?  I think that there are some questions that have already dealt with propaganda, media, etc.

Comment: Editing your question to include an example of what you mean would certainly be good.

Comment: How about "stories"?

Answer (score 2):

There is a phrase, **yellow journalism** or **[yellow press](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yellow+journalism)** that means

> Journalism that exploits, distorts, or exaggerates the news to create sensations and attract readers.

The phrase originated in the late 19th century to describe the extreme sensationalist and exaggerated reporting in the circulation wars between the Hearst and Pulitzer newspaper enterprises.

Some of the reporting was clearly lies, some of it mere flamboyant language and everything in between.

In recent political debates, there have been frequent accusations of *vast right/left wing conspiracies* on the part of various media camps (newspapers supposedly leaning left, talk radio leaning right) that have been characterized by their opponents as little more than lies, innuendo, and distortions to serve partisan ends.

Answer (score 1):

One technical word is *libel*, which is defined as spreading a malicious lie in print.  The equivalent via speech is *slander*.  (A mnemonic for remembering the difference between the two is that the words *speech* and *slander* both begin with the letter S.)

Comment: Libel and slander are good words to know in the context of writing about journalism, but one need not be a journalist to commit libel or slander, so I don't *think* that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MichaelBroder:  You could be right.  The OP's question is a little cryptic, but I gave it a shot anyway.  Don

Comment: Go for it! I don't even think the question is cryptic, I'm just not sure there really is such a word.